# Django Rest Framework :How to serialize many to many field

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

**I have my models Certificates and Suppliers and Suppliers has many to many relationship with certificates**

```
class Certificates(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
        image_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.name}'
    
    
    class Suppliers(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
        location = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
        longitude = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
        latitude = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
        certificates = models.ManyToManyField(Certificates, null=True)
        bio = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
        environmental_info = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
        social_info = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
        governance_info = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.name}'
```

This is my Serializers:

```
class CertificatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Certificates
        fields = '__all__'


class SuppliersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    certificates = CertificatesSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Suppliers
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'certificates')
```

and this is my view

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def supplier_response_list(request):
    suppliers_list = Suppliers.objects.all()
    serializer = SuppliersSerializer(suppliers_list, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

am getting this error:
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `description` on serializer `CertificatesSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `ManyRelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'description'.

Answer (score 2):

You forget to set `many=True` in `certificates = CertificatesSerializer()`

Correct version:

```py
class SuppliersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    certificates = CertificatesSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Suppliers
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'certificates')
```

Witout that DRF think this is one to one relation instead of one to many

Answer (score 1):

Set `many=True` in `certificates = CertificatesSerializer()` like [@sharpek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554732/sharpek) comment

Please, note that `null=True` in `ManyToManyField` is ignored during migrations and when the data are stored

Should use `blank=True` in this case for `m2m` relationship instead of nullable data insert cause not working

Comment: This answer should have been a comment on the other person's post or should have a supporting code example.